# Amount of Free Disk Space Required For Lucene IndexWriter.ExpungeDeletes()

Tags: lucene

I am writing an application that utilizes Lucene indexes where the user has to **frequently update or delete** the indexed documents.

I understand that if someone wants permanent deletion of documents marked for deletion from Lucene Index then he has two options:

1. Indexwriter.Optimize() OR
2. Indexwriter.ExpungeDeletes()

As optimizing the index for every delete session is expensive and time consuming and it  it requires **2X free Disk Space**, so in situations where the disk space is running short, Optimize() did not seem to be a good choice.

So obviously I had to go for ExpungeDeletes() which is claimed to be less time consuming and as it does not force the merging of all segments, so hopefully it does not require that 2x free space.

But still this operation requires some free disk space to successfully merge the specific segments.

So my question is:

**How much free disk is required for ExpungeDeletes() to complete its task successfully?**

I am asking this question because I have tested it with some indexes which had already been optimized and merged into a single segment...and I have found that expungedeletes() succeeds in this case only when the free disk space is at least the same size as index ,else it throws an exception: **MergePolicy-MergeException**

**Also, is there any way I can prevent this exception from being thrown in the above mentioned case?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in JIRA issue [3577](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3577). To summarize: `expungeDeletes` is a poor name because it doesn't merely remove the deletes and leave the rest of the index alone.

If you want to know the exact performance of it: `expungeDeltes` just calls a merge on every segment which has deletes. Which in your case sounds like it could be every segment so... roughly equivalent to calling `optimize`.

What about your searches isn't working that you think it's required for you to optimize?